# Regex to replace apostrophese (') - Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 50

Tags: php, regex

So I am new to regular expressions and I am attempting to write one that will allow me to replace an apostrophe (`'`) with `\'`. The regex that I came up with worked with all my test cases when I tested it on http://myregextester.com, but completely error out when I implement it in my code.

Anyways, this is what I have as of yet:

```
preg_replace('/((?<!\\)\'+(?=\d\ds\b))|(\b(?<=\w)(?<!\\)\'+(?=\w+\b))/','\'',$text);
```

and it throws this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>   Message: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 50

I have counted like twenty times to see where the `)` is not matching up, and to my eyes there is not. Here is one of my several counts:

```
( ( ?<!\\ )'+ ( ?=\d\ds\b ) ) | ( \b ( ?<=\w ) ( ?<!\\ ) '+ ( ?=\w+\b )  )
1 2       3   4           5 6   7    8       9 10      11   12        13 14
```

Any ideas, or pointing out my glaringly obvious mistakes a newbie can't spot would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you `echo`'d the string to see what actually gets passed to `preg_replace`?

Comment: I just double checked and the text I was expecting was passed. For testing sake something along the lines of $text = "'80s '90s don't won't \'30s i\'ve";

Comment: Not the text, the regex!

Comment: So what are you trying to replace? Is the following right?  
Replace: not backslash, then apostrophe (1 or more times), then not digit OR a word boundary OR replace: not word boundary, then word character, then not a backslash, then an apostrophe (1 or more times), then a word character OR a word boundary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\\)` in a **string literal** becomes `\)` - escaped closing parenthesis - in a **regex pattern**, as double backslash sequence is interpolated into a single backslash even within the string literal delimited by single quotation marks. The problem is, though, that `\)` sequence in regex pattern is used to represent a literal `)` symbol (which will otherwise be parsed as a metacharacter).

What you intend to do is probably best written with `\\\\)`. This way each `\\` sequence in a string literal becomes a single `\` in the pattern. The pattern parser will see this:

`\\)`

... a literal backslash symbol, followed by `)` metacharacter.

But it seems to be there's another problem here: in your regex you're looking for some special (a series) of apostrophes, yet replace them with single apostrophe again. Remember, `\'` within a string literal is just that - single quotation mark! You probably meant to use `'\\\''` here instead.

Comment: So, when I do this, it does not error out, but it also does not add the \'s either. So `$text = "'80s '90s don't \'30s i\'ve";
 $text =  preg_replace('/((?<!\\\\)\'+(?=\d\ds\b))|(\b(?<=\w)(?<!\\\\)\'+(?=\w+\b))/','\'',$text);
echo $text;` Test is still unaltered.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here: how do you expect the $text to be altered, if you're looking for single apostroph here, and replace it with single apostroph? Shouldn't you use `'\\\''` as replacement text?

Comment: ah ha! Thanks, I didn't know all the \ had to be applied to the replacement as well. I will mark you answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Where you are escaping inside of a string you also need to escape the escaping character; it's really confusing!

If you want a `\` you need to do `\\\\`

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here?  Why not just this?

```
str_replace("'", "\'", $str)
```

Comment: Looking at the regex I'd say that the question doesn't fully describe the problem they are trying to solve. :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't want it to change single quotes, only apostrophes (so don't or '80s vs 'I am quoting something in here'). I am adding an escape to the apostrophes for some changes I make on the displaying the text later